# what does ""diminishing importance with a decreasing budget""

Tags: meaning-in-context

> For some CIOs, the changing landscape forces
>   them to act as a manager of a cost center of
>   **diminishing importance with a decreasing
>   budget,** narrowly focused on driving efficiencies
>   and reducing costs. For others, it means
>   unprecedented opportunity, increased salary, and
>   a critical ascent into a more strategic leadership
>   position for their organizations. In this eBook,
>   we explore these changes and how CIOs can
>   leverage their expertise to help their organizations
>   succeed in the rapidly evolving landscape.

Comment: The business isn't making as much money in that department as it used to and because of that its budget is being reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we should analyze "diminishing importance" and "with a decreasing budget" as two separate modifiers. The cost center is becoming less important (diminishing importance), and it is also suffering from a smaller and smaller budget (decreasing budget). The sentence emphasizes that there are two negative effects of "the changing landscape" for some CIOs; the following sentence highlights the potential positive effects.